# Argument Exception with ComboBox dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary, bindingsource, argumentexception

So here is my dictionary:

```
// weapon <name, dps>
Dictionary<string, int> weapons = new Dictionary<string, int>();

weapons.Add("Chaotic Staff", 1000);
weapons.Add("Abyssal Whip", 800);
weapons.Add("Death Lotus Darts", 900);
weapons.Add("Drygore Mace", 1200);
```

Here is my attempt to add my dictionary items as a string. For example I want to add in `Chaotic Staff - 1000` as one of the values in the box.

```
var result = string.Join(", ", weapons.Select(m => m.Key + " - " + m.Value).ToArray()); //copied it from somewhere.

weaponsComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(result, null);
weaponsComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
weaponsComboBox.ValueMember = "Value"; //Argument Exception error
```

What should be the correction? I have little to no understanding on BindingSource and LINQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing two things - converting your dictionary to a list of strings, but then trying to bind to the key/value pair from the original dictionary. Do one or the other, but not both.

If you want to bind to the `Dictionary<string,int>` and display only the key:

```
weaponsComboBox.DataSource = weapons;
weaponsComboBox.DisplayMember = "Key";
weaponsComboBox.ValueMember = "Value";
```

If you want to convert the dictionary to a simple list of strings, then there's no reason to set the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`:

```
var result = weapons.Select(x => string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.Key, x.Value)).ToList();

weaponsComboBox.DataSource = result;
```

From what you've posted, I don't think you need to use a `BindingSource` either.

Comment: What I intended is to convert my dictionary <string,int> to a string array that is in the format `WeaponName - DPS`. I tried to delete the DisplayMember and ValueMember lines and make the DataSource as `result` LINQ but it still gives me the same Argument error.

Comment: It is throwing it on `beverageComboBox.DataSource = result;`.

Comment: While it helped remove the error, there is still a logical error. Instead it actually displays a single char as each item in the combobox. Ie, `Chaotic Staff - 1000` would become `["C", "h", "a", "o",....]`

Comment: Thank-you got it! :) I'm kinda a little unfamiliar with LINQ so I blindly googled up that line.